# Resolving Rich text with anchor tags pointing to Iceportal Component

Tags: templating, template-builder, resolving

Hello this is my first post and am a newbie tridion user here.

I have created a component with rich text where I include an hyperlink to an ecl item.
[image]

Then I included the component on a page and published the page. While viewing the page on the browser we see,

[image]

In the source code of the page corresponding to the rich text we see that url for the hyperlink is resolved.

But this is incorrect. I would like to know how this url is resolved for the ecl item? And if possible I want to know how can I resolve the ecl hyperlink with another url which is available in the ecl component it self, how can i do it?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Tridion Stack Exchange, Sabin! Could you share a bit of what you're doing in the Template Building Block code and where you're looking to confirm the replacement when you mention "in the page?" This can help us understand what you're trying to do and where the results might not match your expectations.